# Trouble with UDP ports and DatagramSockets

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, datagram

I'm working on a project that is suppose to send a file from one machine to another using DatagramPackets and DatagramSockets. The implementation is suppose to mimic the TCP protocol. So once the receiver gets a packet it sends back an ACK to the sender, confirming the packet was delivered. My program so far without making any checks for ACKs. Im having trouble implementing the ACK messages. On my receiver program, it shows that the ACKs are being sent, but the sender application is not getting them.

I keep getting an error from creating the socket. "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind". I'm confused because nowhere else in the sender applicaion have a specified the port. I simply use `DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();` 
but I do use 
`DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(packetData, packetData.length, internetAddress, 49000);
            socket.send(packet);` when sending packets.

I have tried removing the datagram declaration in my waitForAck() method and used the same datagramSocket I used to send packets. But `socket.receive(packet);` will hang and never recieve anything because it hasnt been assigned a port to listen on.

This is my method to listen for ACKs:

```
public void waitForACK(){
    //listen for ack for a period of time
    //if ACK received, then break send next packet
    //if ACK not received or time out, send last packet
    //TODO: implement a timeout
    System.out.println("### Sender waiting for ACK");
    try {
        DatagramSocket receivingSocket = new DatagramSocket(49000);
        while (!ACKreceived) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1500]; // Actual Ethernet packet size is 1500 bytes
            // receive request
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            receivingSocket.receive(packet); //socket.receive(packet); <--
            byte[] packetData = Arrays.copyOf(packet.getData(), packet.getLength());
            ACKreceived = checkACK(packetData);//check the recieved packet contains an ACK message
        }
        System.out.println("### Sender recieved ACK");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("### never got ACK");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I've also tried this but the scoket will hang and never actualy recieve anything. Even though the application that recieves the file successfully reports sending an ACK. I'm guessing its because it does not know to recieve the ACK on port 49000.

```
public void waitForACK(){
    //listen for ack for a period of time
    //if ACK received, then break send next packet
    //if ACK not received or time out, send last packet
    //TODO: implement a timeout
    System.out.println("### Sender waiting for ACK");
    try {
        while (!ACKreceived) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1500]; // Actual Ethernet packet size is 1500 bytes
            // receive request
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet); //<--- HANGS RIGHT HERE
            byte[] packetData = Arrays.copyOf(packet.getData(), packet.getLength());
            ACKreceived = checkACK(packetData);//check the recieved packet contains an ACK message
        }
        System.out.println("### Sender recieved ACK");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("### never got ACK");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: On getting a bind error check using tools like netstat if the port is free. 'Already in use' means **certainly** some process is bound to it even if your code is not.  How does your edited code look like? (where you say you removed `Datagram` declaration?

Comment: I edited my post to include to code you asked for. It's just a modified version of my waitForACK() method. In the meantime I'll do some research on netstat.

Comment: Is the other side explicitly sending to port 49000? Local and peer ports are generally not the same, unless you explicitly make them the same, so the fact that you're sending to 49000 doesn't mean you should expect to receive on 49000.

Answer (score 1):

You're leaking sockets.

Don't create a new socket just to wait for an ACK. You should have exactly one `DatagramSocket` open for the life of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the netstat command to check if another program (or even your program) is active on the port. On unix netstat -lp as su will show you, on windows netstat exists too with different command line options

Answer (score -1):

Before we get into the problems with your code: Why is the client trying to listen on port 49000?

If you don't already realize this: the local port and peer port do not have to be the same, and generally are not. When you call `DatagramSocket()`, you get an arbitrary local port assigned by the OS. The fact that you sent to 49000 doesn't change your local port. And if the other side of the connection just sends back to the tuple it received a packet from, that won't arrive at 49000, it will arrive at your local port.

If that's your problem, the fix is to use the second version (just use your existing socket to listen as well as sending), and then fix the other side (that you haven't shown us the code for) to send the ACK to the complete address tuple of the packet's sender, not port 49000 on the sender's host.

---

If you realize that, but think that both sides need to have local port 49000 for some reason… well, they probably don't. Generally, a protocol needs one side (the "server") to have a well-known port to connect, but the other side (the "client") doesn't need that. That's why you can use `DatagramSocket()` instead of `DatagramSocket(49000)` on the client and things work.

Again, same fix.

---

In the rare cases where both sides really *do* need to have a well-known port (e.g., so you can explicit open it in your company's internal firewalls), you almost certainly want the sending to *also* happen on that port.

So, instead of creating a `DatagramSocket()` to send from, and a `DatagramSocket(48000)` to listen on, just create a `DatagramSocket(48000)` in the first place and use it for both.

However, note that this solution, like any solution that uses a fixed port, has two additional problems:

First, if client and server both want to bind port 48000, they can't both run on the same machine. You can renumber one of them to 48001, or just accept that.

Second, if you expect to start and stop the client frequently, it's often going to try to bind port 49000 while the OS still has a socket for that port in `TIME_WAIT` state, so you're going to get a bind error. This is what [`SO_REUSEADDR`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html) is for; use it.

---

What if you really do want to use an arbitrary-port sender on the client, but a fixed-port listener? There are some cases where that makes sense, but unless you can explain why you really need this, you don't have one.

If you do, then, and only then, could you use something like your first version. But you *still* probably want to create the listener socket once, not each time you listen for ACKs; it just should be a different attribute from the sending socket. (And of course you still need to deal with the same things as in the last section.)

And if you really do want to create a new listener socket for each ACK, then you have to make sure you close it immediately, rather than waiting for the Java GC and the OS to collectively get around to closing it for you, or the next time you wait for an ACK, you're likely to get a bind error, because the old listener socket is still bound to it.

Comment: Why should the ACK socket be different from the sending socket?

Comment: @EJP: It shouldn't, except in rare cases. That's the whole point of the answer: unless you have (and need) one of those rare cases, just use the second version of the client, and _fix the server_ to respond to the same port the client sent from.

Comment: @EJP: Note that it's only in the very last version where you need two sockets—where you explicitly need a fixed-port listener on both sides, and you also explicitly need the sending to come from a different port. In that case, it's pretty obvious why the ACK socket should be different from the sending socket—if you really do need different ports, you want separate sockets.

Comment: So what does 'it should be a different attribute from the sending socket' mean? And how exactly could you ever need two different ports?

Comment: @EJP: Look at the context. "If you do [need this very rare case, because none of the "almost always" parts above happen to be true for you], then, and only then, could you use something like your first version." What are you not getting there? (And as for what "it should just be a different attribute from the sending socket" means: it means that, even in the rare case where you need two sockets, you still don't want to create the second one locally and leak it; you want to make it an attribute, like the first one.)

Comment: @EJP: As for "how exactly could you ever need two different ports?", there are real-life protocols that use two ports, from FTP to RTSP; have you never heard of them?